# Spheres are locally conformally flat but have non-zero curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

From my understanding, a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ is locally conformally flat if on some open neighbourhood $U_{\alpha}$ about any point in $M$, there exists a function $f\in C^{\infty}(U_{\alpha})$ such that $\bar{g} = e^f g$ is flat.

Furthermore, $(M,g)$ is (globally) conformally flat if there exists a global function satisfying the above, i.e., $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$.

Now, it is a theorem that every n-sphere is locally conformally flat. We also know that the n-sphere has constant positive curvature, and so taking $f=0$, is conformally non-flat.

I don't see how the sphere can be locally conformally flat with curvature zero at each point locally, but then globally have non-zero curvature. Can't we just restrict the global curvature to $U_{\alpha}$ and it will be non-zero, and so can't be locally conformally flat?

Comment: A metric $g$ is locally conformally flat if there _exists_ a function $f$ such that $\overline{g}=e^f$ is flat, not if this is true for all $f$.  In your situation, the round metric $g$ on the sphere can be written locally as $g=\bigl(\frac{1+r^2}{2}\bigr)^{-2}dx^2$, where $dx^2$ is the Euclidean metric and $r=\lvert x\rvert$.  The point is that it is not enough to check one metric in the conformal class.  In practice, it is easier to apply the following result: In dimension $n\geq4$, a metric $g$ is locally conformally flat if and only if the Weyl tensor vanishes identically.

Comment: Your sentence "so taking =0, is conformally non-flat" on which the question is based, is quite meaningless. Are you saying that conformally flat metric has zero curvature? This would be false.